# Best method for determining if a row exists

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, razor

I am using SQL Server and WebMatrix Razor syntax to try and determine is a username is contained within a table called Users.

The logic I wish to have is :

```
 bool usernameExists = db.QueryValue("SELECT Username from Users where Username = ?", username);
 if(usernameExists.IsEmpty()){ //username is not in table
    Response.Redirect("Register.cshtml");
 }
```

What is the best practice for going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is probably:

```
bool usernameExists = db.QueryValue("SELECT usernameExists = CASE WHEN EXISTS 
 (SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE Username = ?) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END", username);

if (!usernameExists) { Response.Redirect("Register.cshtml"); }
```

Though I'm speaking strictly from the SQL Server side. I don't know if this is the best approach from the C# side.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for. When I try and run this SQL query it results in the error - "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 23,Token in error = = ]", however. Can you think of any reason why this may be happening?

Comment: Is it possibly because Razor might have a very limited SQL vocabulary? You can certainly put that kind of logic in a stored procedure and call that (probably where your logic should be IMHO).

Comment: Even running the query directly in SQL Server returns the error "---------------------------
Database Manager
---------------------------
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 23,Token in error = = ]
---------------------------
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 23,Token in error = = ]". Any ideas?

Comment: What is "Database Manager"? Did you try running it in a query window in Management Studio? Did you create a stored procedure that does it, then call the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to [implement a custom membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) which authenticates against your own user table. You application is then decoupled from the specifics of user storage and it's a well understood model for user authentication in ASP.NET applications.

Comment: In my case I am using an external server to authenticate users, and the first time they sign into my site I want to redirect them to an area where they add some info, so while that is certainly the best way of doing this in most cases, I dont think it is for me.

Comment: That's fair enough, but I'm not sure why the fact that you're authenticating against an external server should affect the possibility of implementing authentication with the membership provider model.