# Razor check if row exists

Tags: sql, database, razor

I am trying to do a check on the input data, to see if it already exists in the database.

I have tried this, but it did not help:
[Best method for determining if a row exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649814/best-method-for-determining-if-a-row-exists)

I am still new to Razor, but getting better by the day :-)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `QueryValue` method:

```
var db = Database.Open("SmallBakery");
var count = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product WHERE Id = @0", 123);
if (count > 0) {
    // the record exists
}
```

You will of course need to adapt the SQL query to match your database schema.

Useful read: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/more-resources/asp-net-web-pages-api-reference

Comment: +1 Is the `db` variable made available by the framework, or do you have to declare it yourself?

Comment: No, it's not made available. You need to instantiate it: `var db = Database.Open("SmallBakery");`. I will update my answer.

Comment: And I suppose `SmallBakery` is defined in the `Web.config` file?

Comment: Yes, it's either the name of the connection string or it will directly look for a `SmallBakery.sdf` file in your `App_Data`.